# PDF file downloads getting corrupted on PC

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, pdf, download

In my laptop certain PDF files are getting corrupted on downloading. The downloads happen just fine without an issue, but when I try to open the downloaded PDF file later, I get a "Format error: Not a PDF or corrupted" message. I have tried opening the PDF files with multiple PDF viewers with all of them showing similar errors. Note that this happens only with some PDF downloads. Other types of files work fine after downloading.

In fact today I had to download a very important PDF file, but could not open it due to this issue. In the end I had to download it on my Android phone and bluetooth it to my laptop. This issue persists across browsers.

Some details:
OS: Windows 10.

Browser: latest versions of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Chrome is my primary browser.

Extensions: Ghostery and AdBlock plus on both Chrome and Firefox. I had uMatrix javascript blocker on Chrome, but I disabled it after it broke too many sites.

Download Manager: EagleGet.

EagleGet may be the issue, but when I disable it and try to download the same PDF file I get a "session timed out" error in the website from which I'm attempting the download.

Like I said this does not happen to all PDF downloads, and currently the only PDF download where I'm facing this issue is the one in the website that gives me a "Session timed out" error when I attempt the download with EagleGet disabled (which is super weird). None of this weird behavior happens with Chrome on Android.

Unfortunately I don't remember when this started happening. This has been going on for a while but I started paying attention to it only after some important downloads got corrupted.

Could this be a virus issue? (I have Malwarebytes and Windows Defender, and have not noticed any other suspicious behavior from anything otherwise) What can I do to solve this extremely annoying problem?

Comment: if you suspect virus/malware, don't rely on the on-access checking. update the software, and do a full scan.

Comment: Are all the PDFs from a single site? I would suspect that the site has problems (hence the session timed out).

Comment: @YisroelTech the PDF corrupted issue is not limited to one site, but when I encountered this problem previously I did not try disabling EagleGet and hence I do not know if the session timed out error would be an issue with that as well. Yet to encounter this problem in website that does not require login.